# How does spacetime curvature explain why it is easier to go downhill than uphill?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, everyday-life, curvature

Gravity is spacetime curvature. Without mixing Newton's view of gravity, how does a purely spacetime curvature view of gravity explain why it is easier to bike downhill than uphill or why did the apple fall down and not go up?  Does the spacetime curvature have a sense of direction?

Thanks

Comment: Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity
The fact that it's easier to bike downhill, is due to a better alignment between your path and a geodesic path that your bike would like to take through spacetime. It is the earth pushing back on your bike that is preventing them from taking this path, which is also the reason why accelerometers on the surface of the earth give a reading. When you bike downhill, this reading should show a reduced value in proportion to the steepness of the hill (in particular, in free fall: zero reading).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of talk about space-time curvature, but when it comes down to it the reason that you fall down rather than up is because of time dilation. Time runs slower the closer you get to the center of a planet. Nobel laureate Kip Thorn referred to Einstein's law of time warps. He said "things like to live where they age the most slowly. Gravity pulls them there.  And so as an application, the Earth's mass warps time according to Einstein. It slows time near the surface of the earth. And this time warp is what produces gravity."

I think the space-time model of a bowling ball in a trampoline is very misleading. I like to think of gravity more like a low pressure system in the weather. There is less time pressure near the planet and things fall to that lower pressure region, just like the wind blows leaves into the lower pressure area in the weather. Time runs faster in the space above the falling object than it does in the space below the object. So the object moves towards the region where time is running slower.

Remember that everything that is high up has potential energy. When things Fall they give up that potential energy. This is squarely into the third law of thermodynamics that all things tend towards entropy. By falling, the object gives up energy and creates more entropy.

So in answer to your general question, your bicycle rolls downhill because time runs slower as you go down the hill.

Comment: why would an object prefer to be in a place where time runs slower?

Comment: As I said above because doing so increases entropy. Potential energy is converted into various other energies, therefore entropy increases. This is in the third law of thermodynamics that all things tend towards increasing entropy. But from a much easier point of view just think of it as a low pressure system as I described. A low pressure system in time.